# Systematic replace part of variable name with 1st element of an associated R vector

Tags: r, regex

I have a dataframe in which the 1st element of an associated 'name' vector is related to subsequent named numerical vectors. I am attempting to replace the meaningless number with the 1st element of the associated name vector.

Here is an example dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(data.0.name = c("A", "A", "A"), data.0.one_minute_ago =     c(1,2,1), data.0.one_hour_ago = c(2,2,3), 
                 data.1.name = c("B", "B", "B"), data.1.one_minute_ago =     c(3,3,2), data.1.one_hour_ago = c(5,6,2))`
```

Each `number.name` vector is associated with a construct (either A or B in this case) and each `number.time` is associated with a time dimension. So, `data.0.one_minute_ago` is actually the number of A's you had one_minute_ago.

What I would like to do (because I have a large dataset with lots of the transformations) is to replace the `number.dimension` with the `construct.dimension`, and of course do that for each `number.` from 0:9

I've written some grep code to begin with this task, but to no avail (I am stuck with retaining everything after the `number.`

```
grep( "data.[0-9].name" ,names(df), perl=TRUE)
as.character(df[1, 1])
as.character(df[1, 4])
as.character(names(df[2]))
as.character(names(df[3]))
as.character(names(df[5]))
as.character(names(df[6]))

df.1 <- (df[1, grep( "data.[0-9].name" ,names(df))])


df.1 <- (df[1, grep( "data.[0-9].name" ,names(df))])
df.1 <- data.frame(lapply(df.1, as.character), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
constructs <- as.character(df.1[1,c(1:2)])
```

Here the 1st and 2nd element of `constructs` are the constructs associated with `0.name`/`0.dimension` and `1.name`/`1.dimension` respectively.

```
constructs [1]
constructs [2]
```

From there, I'm fairly certain the code would involve some `names(df)[] <-` but am uncertain on where to go from here.

Any and all help appreciated.

EDIT: here is the desired variable name output: simply changing the variable names (and of course retain the values associated with the variable names:

```
data.A.name   data.A.one_minute_ago    data.A.one_hour_ago    data.B.name    data.B.one_minute_ago    data.B.one_hour_ago
```

EDIT 2: In my true dataset, the number of repetitions per dimensions (i.e., one_minute_ago, one_hour_ago, one_day_ago) can vary across construct (i.e, two dimensions for one construct and 3 for another, and 9 for another). I would like the solution to take that into account.

Here is a modified sample dataset to reflect this subtlety:

```
df <- data.frame(data.0.name = c("A", "A", "A"), data.0.one_minute_ago = c(1,2,1), data.0.one_hour_ago = c(2,2,3), 
             data.1.name = c("B", "B", "B"), data.1.one_minute_ago = c(3,3,2), data.1.one_hour_ago = c(5,6,2), 
             data.2.name = c("C", "C", "C"), data.2.one_minute_ago = c(3,3,2), data.2.one_hour_ago = c(5,6,2), data.2.one_day_ago = c(3,2,3))
```

Comment: What is the desired output given your example dataframe?

Comment: @JasonAizkalns I edited the end of the post to reflect the desired varnames transformation: I didn't include the values associated with the variables, because frankly I don't know how to format on SO that way.

Comment: No problem, I think the question is clear now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We create a grouping 'indx' based on the 'number' in the column names. `split` the column names based on the 'indx' ('lst').  Get one element from the columns having 'name' as suffix ('r1').  Use 'Map' and `gsub` to replace the 'number' in each element of 'lst' with that of 'r1'.

```
 indx <- gsub('[^0-9]+', '', names(df))
 lst <- split(names(df), indx)
 r1 <- as.character(unlist(df[1,grep('name', names(df))]))
 lst2 <- Map(function(x,y) gsub('[0-9]+', y, x), lst, r1)
 names(df) <- unsplit(lst2, indx)
 names(df)
 # [1] "data.A.name"           "data.A.one_minute_ago" "data.A.one_hour_ago"  
 #[4] "data.B.name"           "data.B.one_minute_ago" "data.B.one_hour_ago"  
 #[7] "data.C.name"           "data.C.one_minute_ago" "data.C.one_hour_ago"  
 #[10] "data.C.one_day_ago"
```

Comment: This is it!! Had never used `Map()` - good use case for certain. Thank you very much - I wish I could accept it 100X :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think this works:

```
library(stringr)
splits        <- str_split(names(df), "\\.")
trailing_name <- sapply(splits, "[[", 3)
constructs    <- rep(constructs, each = 3)
constructs
# [1] "A" "A" "A" "B" "B" "B"
names(df)     <- str_c("data", constructs, trailing_name, sep=".")
names(df)
# [1] "data.A.name"           "data.A.one_minute_ago" "data.A.one_hour_ago"   "data.B.name"          
# [5] "data.B.one_minute_ago" "data.B.one_hour_ago"
```

Comment: Thanks @JasonAizkalns, however I think that any introduction of a new dimension (e.g., `data.2.one_day_ago`) could break this code. That is, the `rep` aspect of the script would work, given that there are always 3 repetitions of `.name` and `.dimension` Unfortunately, the number of reps vary across construct. I will go back and edit my op.